# Term to describe something which represents either a field or a property of a type

Tags: .net, oop

I am doing some reflection based work and a term to describe something which represents either a field or a property of a type has eluded me. I know that fields, properties, and methods are collectively referred to as members, but what about just fields and properties? Does such a standard term exist?

Comment: I'm not sure, but is a property more similar to a field or to a method, in your eyes?  It seems to be a matter of perspective.

Comment: @John Zwinck - Good point! Typically, I tend to think of properties  as more similar methods. But in this context, as more similar to fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of these terms: FieldOrProperty, Member, DataMember.

Comment: Thanks Martin - I like DataMember

Answer (score 2):

You can use **attribute**, which is used in general OOP terminology (e.g., UML) but that could be confused with .NET custom attributes or C# language attributes. In some contexts, a **member** means *field or property*, excluding methods, as in [`MemberExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression.aspx).